How Access Data When Custom Object Visibility Set To Protected
I have created an appexchange package but have hit an issue at security review. The custom object holds credential information and the reviewer asked that I mark the custom object visibility as Protected.
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <visibility>Protected</visibility>
    ...
</CustomObject>

But, when I do the change I lose complete access to the objects data, even in the managed package. It's like the object simply doesn't exist.
How, if a custom object is protected do you access the data within a managed package?
I was able to set the object visibility to PackageProtected which still allows the package to access the object and data. But the doc page that discusses the visibility attribute suggests that only custom metadata can use this attribute type - CustomObject Metadata

Public—If the custom object, custom setting, or custom metadata type is packaged, it’s accessible to all subscribing orgs.
Protected—If the custom object, custom setting, or custom metadata type is in a managed package, it’s accessible only to the developer org. Subscribing orgs can’t access it.
PackageProtected— (Custom metadata type only) If the custom metadata type is PackageProtected, it’s only accessible by the custom Apex code in the package. Use this value to secure secrets such as API access keys and security tokens. Available in API version 47.0 and later.

Does anybody know if PackageProtected can be used to protect custom object data?
